# Validating Cyrillic input in PHP

Tags: php, localization

Is there a way (regular expression?) to check if a string is composed only of Cyrillic alphanumeric characters?

I need to validate an input to be in range of the Cyrillic alphabet, plus numbers, dashes and spaces

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\p{Cyrillic}` matches Cyrillic characters (you can use **Arabic**, **Greek**, etc. for other alphabets)

`\d` matches numbers

`\s` matches whitespace characters

`\-` matches dashes

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
    $pattern  = "/^[\p{Cyrillic}\d\s\-]+$/u";
    $subjects = array(12, "ab", "АБ", '--', '__');

    foreach($subjects as $subject){
        $match = (bool) preg_match($pattern, $subject);
        if($match)  
            echo "$subject matches the testing pattern<br />";
        else
            echo "$subject does not match the testing pattern<br />";
    }
?>
```

Comment: this does exactly what I need. Thanks Nabil